# Error in installing passenger nginx module

Tags: nginx, passenger

I am getting an error in installing passenger nginx in MAC 10.14.

here are the logs:

```sh
src/cxx_supportlib/vendor-modified/boost/atomic/detail/ops_gcc_x86_dcas.hpp:408:16: error: 
      address argument to atomic builtin cannot be const-qualified
      ('const volatile
      boost::atomics::detail::gcc_dcas_x86_64::storage_type *' (aka
      'const volatile unsigned __int128 *') invalid)
        return __sync_val_compare_and_swap(&storage, value, value);
               ^                           ~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [c++ -o buildout/support-binaries/AgentFundamentals.o  -Isrc/agent -Isrc/cxx_supportlib -Isrc/cxx_supportlib/vendor-copy -Isrc/cxx_supportlib/vendor-modified -Isrc/cxx_supportlib/vendor-modified/libev -Wno-ambiguous-member-template -Isrc/cxx_supportlib/vendor-copy/libuv/include -Isrc/cxx_supportlib/vendor-copy/websocketpp -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-ambiguous-member-template -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -g -fno-limit-debug-info -std=gnu++11 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-format-nonliteral -DHAS_UNORDERED_MAP -c src/agent/Shared/Fundamentals/Implementation.cpp]
/Users/narendrakumawat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4115/gems/passenger-6.0.2/build/support/cplusplus.rb:53:in `run_compiler'
/Users/narendrakumawat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4115/gems/passenger-6.0.2/build/support/cplusplus.rb:104:in `compile_cxx'
/Users/narendrakumawat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4115/gems/passenger-6.0.2/build/support/cplusplus.rb:162:in `block in define_cxx_object_compilation_task'
/Users/narendrakumawat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4115/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/narendrakumawat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4115/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => nginx => nginx_without_native_support => buildout/support-binaries/PassengerAgent => buildout/support-binaries/AgentFundamentals.o
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I already tried this also : 
https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2199